# .htaccess require rulest internal error 500 or allow from everywhere

Tags: apache, .htaccess, require, apache2.4

before you close my post i've watched every answer which i found and i can't resolve my problem.
In this case i want to make my website accessable only from one ip using **.htaccess like in apache 2.2**.

This is my code:

```
    <Limit GET POST PUT>
Require all denied
Require ip xx.xx.xx.xx
</Limit>
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And now, im trying to make it on **ISPConfig using apache 2.4**. Everytime when im changing the "xx.xx.xx.xx" address for my ISPConfig address website works fine, but can be reached from everywhere, in this way i tried to delete my **require ip** ... then my website shows ispconfig default -"It works!"..
Also when im trying to use **require ip**  this is still doesnt work...

Comment: Could it be that your site operates behind some proxy, so that _all_ requests originate from the same ip address? Did you check the requesting addresses in the http server's access log file?

Comment: It is possible. This website stays behind the Sophos XG Firewall. Now this looks like that: Website on ISPConfig -> Record A on another ISPConfig which provides DNS names.

Comment: Sorry, that does not tell me much, a firewall usually is not a proxy, but that might be a product name here instead of a technically correct term... So it stands: did you check the access log file for the requesting IP addresses? I ask because: _if_ all requests appear to come from some frontend system (be it that firewall or a load balancer or whatever), then certainly the http server cannot somehow distinguish between the requests. That would explain the behavior you describe. What I still do not understand in your question is the http status 500 you mention - when does it occur?